# Determinar si una frase es oración comparativa

Tags: sintaxis

¿Es la parte en negrita una oración comparativa?

> *Así fue siempre María, más parecida a doña Julia, su abuela materna, **que si hubiera sido su hija**.

¿Acaso no debería ser ***como si*** hubiera sido...?

Comment: La construcción me suena rara. ¿Es de algún libro?

Answer (score 1):

Sí, lo es. "Que si hubiera sido su hija" es una [proposición subordinada adverbial comparativa](http://www.gramaticas.net/2012/06/ejemplos-de-subordinadas-adverbiales_3633.html) de superioridad. La frase completa sería:

> Así fue siempre María, más parecida a doña Julia, su abuela materna, que [lo parecida que habría sido a doña Julia] si hubiera sido su hija.

En términos un poco más abstractos, la comparación podría expresarse como "María es más parecida a A que a B", donde:

- A = doña Julia, su abuela materna.
- B = ella misma en el caso hipotético de que doña Julia hubiese sido su madre en vez de su abuela materna.

O en términos de "A es más que B", donde:

- A = lo que se parece María a doña Julia, su abuela materna.
- B = lo que se habría parecido María a doña Julia si esta hubiese sido su madre en vez de su abuela materna.

Si se cambia "que si" por "como si" también se cambia el sentido de la oración. Esto es, la frase:

> (1) Así fue siempre María, más parecida a doña Julia, su abuela materna, como si hubiera sido su hija.

...contiene una comparación, pero solo hay un término explícito. El segundo término, con el que se compara el primero, se sobreentiende:

> (2) Así fue siempre María, más parecida a doña Julia, su abuela materna, [que a su propia madre]. ¡Vaya, como si hubiera sido su hija!

La oración (1) suena un tanto extraña: está incompleta y contiene un añadido ("como si hubiera sido su hija") que no se relaciona con el resto de la frase lo suficiente como para estar separado con solo una coma. Podría aparecer en un diálogo reflejando, por ejemplo, el habla espontánea, pero es un empeoramiento sobre la oración original. La oración (2) suena un poco mejor que la (1), pero no significa lo mismo que la original.